# ArgumentNullException trying to navigate in Xamarin Forms

Tags: wordpress, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to access a list of categories and posts in a WordPress page, and I'm using this code,

```
var result = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("my.page.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories"));
```

or this code, just for debugging:

```
webView.Source = "https://www.google.com";
```

and I get this error:

```
12-19 21:54:08.131 I/MonoDroid(26537): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
12-19 21:54:08.251 I/MonoDroid(26537): System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
12-19 21:54:08.251 I/MonoDroid(26537): Parameter name: key
```

Any suggestion?

Regards.

Comment: your first example isn't a valid URI

Comment: It is just an example. I use a real URL, and I can get the result in a browser.

Comment: are you sure the exception is generated by those lines?  Have you tried wrapping them in a try/catch?  And a browser is generally a lot more forgiving with URL formats than the Uri class is

Comment: The exception isn't catched, even if I use Exception or ArgumentNullException

Comment: This only happens with new views. I copied the same code on existing views and the code works...

Comment: It was my mistake. I made a bad configuration using a RelativeView, so the error cames when the WebView component is shown